# C# site manipulation

Tags: c#

I need have some site manipulation from C# programming language (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010). It is site "http://m.vk.com" . I authorized on this site. It was everything normal. First web-page after authorization it was my profile page. But when I passed to another page this site I loosed my authorization. Another site page was displayed but in non authorization mode. I saved and wrote cookies files to another query. I write next my C# programming code:

I used these directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

It is main function code which started after main button pushing:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string login = textBox1.Text;
     string pass = textBox2.Text;
     bool avt = http_auth_vk(login, pass);

     if (avt == true)
     {
         toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Succes authorization !";
     }
     else 
     {
         toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Authorization data incorrect !";
     }
 }
```

This is the function "http_auth_vk" :

```
    public bool http_auth_vk(string login, string pass)
    {
        //*****************************
        //Получаем action_url
        //*****************************
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        System.Net.WebRequest reqGET = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://m.vk.com/");
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = reqGET.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();


        //*****************************
        //Парсим
        //*****************************
        // Создаём экземпляр класса
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        // Загружаем в класс (парсер) наш html
        doc.LoadHtml(s);
        // Извлекаем значения
        HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='cont']/form");
        // Выводим на экран значиение атрибута src
        // у изображения, которое находилось
        // в теге <div> в слассом bla
        string result1 = bodyNode.Attributes["action"].Value;

        //*****************************
        //POST запрос
        //*****************************
        var cookies = new CookieContainer();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(result1);
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            writer.Write("email=" + login + "&pass=" + pass);
        }

        using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //*****************************
            //Парсим, поиск ID
            //*****************************                 
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();                
            doc2.LoadHtml(result);
            string result2;
            try
            {
                //textBox3.Text = result;

                HtmlNode bodyNode2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='user_wrap']/a");
                result2 = bodyNode2.Attributes["href"].Value.Substring(3);
                //Если ID найден, то авторизация удалась



                //ПЕРЕХОД НА СТРАНИЦУ ГРУППЫ

                //string sLocation = myHttpWebResponse.Headers["Location"];

                // получам cookie
                string sCookies = "";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"]))
                {
                    sCookies = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
                }

                MessageBox.Show(sCookies);

                // формируем запрос
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://m.vk.com/id100669061");
                //myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);

                myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; MyIE2;";
                myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
                myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru");
                myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sCookies))
                {
                    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sCookies);
                }

                // выполняем запрос
                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();


                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

                textBox3.Text = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();


                MessageBox.Show(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());


                //Console.WriteLine(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
                //Console.ReadKey();



                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                //textBox3.Text = result;

                //Если ID не науден, то авторизация не удалась
                MessageBox.Show("Authorization error !");

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

How I can save authorization, after next page pass?

Comment: "I saved and wirted cookies files to another querie." - Are you send them back to the server in the next page?

Comment: Are you sure? Sorry, I think you are not saving the cookies to future usage.

From what I see, you are using the cookies for the first request after the autentication but you are not saving them to future usage.

Comment: Dear, Bruno Costa. Could you give me example of correcet programm code. I trying of any of combination cookies save. But it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

After a little investigation I believe I found your problem. The .NET framework will take care the cookies for you, you don't need to worry about setting the cookie or save the cookie for later use, but you do need to use the same CookieContainer for all requests.

So first set the cookie container you would like to use:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

You can remove this, as well, all piece of code that uses sCookies.

```
string sCookies = "";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"]))
{
      sCookies = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
}
MessageBox.Show(sCookies);
```

And in the second/third request instead of having this:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sCookies))
        {
            myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sCookies);
        }
```

You need to have this (CookieContainer)

```
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
```